# Recursing through a directory in java, I want to skip a step on the top level

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to output a list of files within a directory recursively (not including the name of the name of the directory that I am starting with (just the contents of it and all files recursing down the tree after that)

here is what I have at the minute. It Might have errors here and there, but the idea is that it will print all the names of every file in the tree recursively. My problem is that I don't want it to print the name of the directory in which they live.

I think my problem is that I am using System.out.println at the start of the recursive method, which means it gets used every time. Which is desirable behavior for every directory BELOW the first one. Its an annoying little problem that I could use some help on. Thanks in advance.

```
public static void listFiles(String path)
{
    File basedir = new File(path);

    System.out.println(path.getName());

    try
    {
        File[] files = basedir.listFiles();

        for (File file : files)
        {
            // If Dealing with a directory, call recursively to the function
            if (file.isDirectory())
            {
                listFiles(file.getPath());
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(file.getName());
            }
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void listFiles(String path, boolean firstCall)
{
    File basedir = new File(path);
    if(!firstCall)
    {
       System.out.println(path.getName());
    }

    try
    {
        File[] files = basedir.listFiles();

        for (File file : files)
        {
            // If Dealing with a directory, call recursively to the function
            if (file.isDirectory())
            {
                listFiles(file.getPath(), false); //false here because it is not the first call
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(file.getName());
            }
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Add a boolean parameter that specifies if it is the first call.  When you call the method pass true to the parameter.  Also `path.getName()` is not valid String doesn't have a function getName() maybe you meant `basedir.getName()`...also remove try catch block IOException can't occur there.